# Variation of Cayley's formula on $K_n$ with one edge missing.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

Given a complete graph $K_n$ with vertices $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $n \choose 2$ edges, let $A_n$ be the graph $K_n$ without the edge $\{1,2\}$.

I need to find and prove the number of induced subtrees on $A_n$. By Cayley's formula, I know that there are $n^{n-2}$ induced subtrees on $K_n$. I was thinking of using the [counting trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)#Counting_trees) method to come up with an expression.

Starting with the vertices from $K_n$ without any edges, I do the following $n-1$ times:

At each step, I choose a vertex $v$, and a second vertex $w$ which has no incident edge so far. Then I add $\{v,w\}$ to the graph.
At step $k$, there are $n$ possible choices for $v$ and $n-k$ choices for $w$.

However, at each step I need to take into account the fact that if either $1$ or $2$ is chosen as $v$, then $2$ and $1$ cannot respectively be chosen as $w$

Without this restriction, there are in total $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}n(i-1)=n^{n-2}n!$ possible choices. How can I come up with a similar formula that satisfies the restriction that vertices $1$ and $2$ cannot have an edge between them?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I figured out that the formula is $\frac{n-2}{n} \times n!$, but I am still unsure how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: How many edges are in each tree?  What proportion of the $n^{n-2}$ trees have edge $\{1,2\}$?

---

Note that each tree has $n-1$ edges and $K_n$ has $\binom{n}{2}$ total edges.  By symmetry, this implies that $\frac{n-1}{\binom{n}{2}}\cdot n^{n-2} = \frac{2}{n}\cdot n^{n-2}$ subtrees of $K_n$ have the edge $\{1,2\}$.  Thus, the number without is simply $n^{n-2} - \frac{2}{n}\cdot n^{n-2} = \frac{n-2}{n}\cdot n^{n-2}$.

Comment: I wrote an algorithm that executes the double counting method I linked (which find $n^{n-2} \times n!$), at I found that for n=3, 12 out of 18 trees (2/3) don't have the edge, for n=4 288 out of 384 (3/4) don't and for n=5, 12 000 out of 15 000 (4/5) don't, so based on these results it seems that $\frac{n-1}{n}$ of the trees don't have the edge $\{1,2\}$ and that $\frac{1}{n}$ do. However I am not sure how to prove this result, as I just deduced it from my algorithm. Also this result is for counting trees, but I assume I can just divide the result by $n!$ to get the actual answer.

Comment: I modified the algorithm to calculate the actual number of trees by removing duplicates and the values I got are 1 when n=3, 8 when n=4, 75 when n=5 and 864 when n=6. I still can't figure out what the pattern is.

Comment: Oh could it simply be $\frac{n-2}{n} \times n^{n-2}$? It seems to work, but how can I prove this?

Comment: @user1354784 Yes, it's $\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot n^{n-2}$.  I added the complete argument.